# Sharing classes between modules on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I am working on a project using [camunda-workflow](https://github.com/amalagaura/camunda-workflow) to communicate with Camunda from a Rails app. camunda-workflow finds the method to execute by mapping the Camunda process key to a module with the same name, and a task's id to the class name.

The issue is that with two closely related processes which share most of the same tasks I would need to have two modules, each one with almost all the same classes. To avoid this I want to either include the classes from one module into another, or from a parent into both.

For these modules

```
module ModuleA
  class ClassA
    def my_method
      puts 'ModuleA, classA method'
    end
  end
end

module ModuleB
end
```

I need to be able to call

```
ModuleB::ClassA.new.my_method
```

How do I share these common classes across the modules to avoid duplication?

Comment: Maybe `include ModuleA` in `ModuleB`?

Comment: @iGian I tried that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do this with [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

```
require "active_support/concern"

module ModuleA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    class ClassA
      def module_a_class_a
        puts 'ModuleA, classA method'
      end
    end
  end
end

module ModuleB
  include ModuleA
end
```

Now I can access the methods of ClassA from ModuleB:

```
ModuleB::ClassA.new.module_a_class_a
```